# Amazon Simple Email Service - Need to send email

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email using SES and the PHP SDK v3. But it's proving rather difficult. This is as far as I've got:

```
require_once '/src/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

$ses = new Aws\Ses\SesClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'mykeyhere',
        'secret' => 'mysecrethere',
    ],
]);
```

I've tried copying code from various guides, but none of it seems to work. Can someone show me how to send an email with php?

Comment: Why vote me down? I've been searching for hours for a simple working example, but they simply don't exist.

Comment: Maybe you meant `Aws\Ses\SesClient`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [AWS API V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html)**

First set up your SES:

```
$ses = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory([
    'key' => 'AWS_KEY',
    'secret' => 'AWS_SECRET_KEY',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
]);
```

Than send email:

```
$ses->sendEmail([
    'Source' => 'from@email.com',
    'Destination' => [
        'ToAddresses' => array('to@email.com')
    ],
    'Message' => array(
        'Subject' => [
            'Data' => 'SES Testing',
            'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
        ],
        'Body' => [
            'Html' => [
                'Data' => '<b>My HTML Email</b>',
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ],
        ],
    ),
]);
```

---

**Few things to note**

1. You have to verify your sender email or sender url to use SES.
2. If you don't *Request Production Access*, than you have to verify all **receivers** emails.
3. You can use any PHP library to send using SES, no need for AWS Api

Comment: if email isn't sent is there any way to get the error that caused it not to be sent?

Comment: @AmyNeville Depends on what you mean "email isn't sent". Some errors may be `try{} catch`'ed, some are not catch able (like wrong email address or something like that).

Comment: Ah, I think I managed to send one - the "verify all receivers" part was what had me stumped. Why don't they allow you to send even 200 emails with sandbox? They are taking this anti-spam too far! It is obstructing developers!

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked how to use in SES API, but I use PHPMailer for this task. result will be same.

```
<?php
    require (dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
        $name    = $_POST['name'];      
        $email   = $_POST['email'];
        $msg     = $_POST['message'];

        // send email
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();     
        $mail->isHTML(false);       
        $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';  // Or put your zone here
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;        
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";          
        $mail->Username = 'mykeyhere';                          
        $mail->Password = 'mysecrethere';  

        $mail->setFrom('<email added in ses>', "$name");
        $mail->addAddress('<destination email>');    

        $mail->Subject = "design2co.de";
        $mail->Body    = "Nome: $name \n" .
                         "Email: $email \n" .
                         "Mensagem: $msg \n";

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 404));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 200));
            exit;
    }
} 
?>
```